# arp -a shows single MAC id of the vlan enable switch not the connected PC

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a cisco switch 4510R which is configured VLAN in this and connected to windows 2008 server. The problem here is when i run arp -a in windows 2008 server it shows IP address Different and shows MAC ID of the device Switch not the MAC ID of the PC. is there any configuration in windows 2008 server to show MAC id of the PC connected to the different VLAN.

I can see the IP address but MAC id is seen only the Switch, only one MAC ID If i connect 100 PCs in the VLAN. If any help me out i will not forget you for my life

Thanks

Lokendro

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question exactly but if you're trying to see the MAC address of a host on another VLAN then you can't. A VLAN is a boundary between hosts in different VLAN's.

Communication between hosts in different VLAN's goes through a router (in your case a layer 3 switch). When communicating with a host in another VLAN/Network a host will ARP for it's Default Gateway and send the traffic there. The MAC address of the Default Gateway will then go into the ARP table on the source host. You'll never see the MAC address of the destination host because the source host does not perform ARP for the destination host, because it isn't local to the source host. This is basic networking.